# How mvc pattern is implemented in iOS user interface? (view-based XCode temlpate)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, viewcontroller

I'm new to iphone development. There's a lot of books on this topic available. But most of the beginner's guides are mostly concerned with Interface Builder usage and lack the information about existing built in XCode code templates or something that could help me in understanding MVC implementation in code. I found that it is possible to write working iOS program without ViewController at all. Well, it seems to me like that after working with the sample code called ViewTransitions.

So, the question is - why is that possible to avoid ViewController implementation in a program that has an interface with a button? If the answer is going to be too long, could you please recommend kind of tutorial or manual covering this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in ViewTransitions, there IS an App Delegate, which is kind of your sole "controller". Even ViewTransitions has:

```
transition.delegate = self;
```

IOS is a bit different from some frameworks in that you aren't as "in control" of what is going on. It often uses a delegation model where you set your code as the delegate, but it (IOS) is in control. Still, you can write in MVC style, it's just your "C" isn't fully in charge.

Comment: `UIViewController`s do a lot of work for you, but you are certainly not required to use them. There's no reason you can't use your own fully-custom view controller if you wanted to. You would end up re-writing an extraordinary amount of Apple's code, though.

Comment: I'm not sure extraordinary is the right word but it depends on the app. It's probably a good learning experience writing some simple app for educational purposes without UIViewController. The result is likely to be that UIViewController isn't doing as much as you thought.

Comment: @user697562 And this is exactly what i've done recently. After some Internet search i found this example: [link](http://tungchingkai.blogspot.com/2008/05/two-versions-of-hello-world-sdk-vs-open.html). Then i created a window-based iOS project and deleted all the sources and NIB, all the things, except several files that had pretty straightforward meaning to me. I also removed a link to NIB from the plist file. I had to change the program structure because of usage UIApplicationMain, but it doesn't matter. iOS app with window works without controller and even without the NIB-files.

Answer (score 1):

@user697562's answer is essentially correct: in the case of ViewTransitions, the role of the controller is played by the app delegate. The app does next to nothing -- it just switches betweeen two views to demonstrate several possible transition effects -- so a UIViewController isn't really needed there.

Notice that there's also nothing in ViewTransitions that you could really call a model object. If you're looking for a strong example of MVC, ViewTransitions isn't the best project to look at. Other sample projects, such as TheElements, give a better demonstration of MVC in action.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called delegation. A concept which helps maintain MVC. It helps to keep the model separate from controllers. For eg: - UITableView/UICollectionView , which knows how to display the data and other ui stuff.
But it does not know which cell to display or what data to display at a particular index.  And this is where delegation and the delegate object comes into place.  UICollectionView handles all the view part whereas all the non view part is handled by the delgate object, which gives the required data for the view. This way a delegate(usually a separate view controller) acts as a data source and UICollectionView as a ui renderer.